# prove a recursive function by induction

Tags: induction, recursion

I have a homework assignment that requires me to prove a recursive function through induction. It seems like that I am stuck on simple algebraic properties and I can't figure it out... If you can, please direct me to the properties(examples would be awesome) instead of the solution. I feel like I really need to solve this one myself to find inner peace.

Given : **T(n) = { 0 if n = 0;  5 if n=1; 3T(n-1) + 4T(n-2) if n > 1}**
Prove by induction that for all natural numbers n, **T(n) = 4<sup>n</sup> - (-1)<sup>n</sup>**

The following is my logic,
since I have to prove **T(n+1)**, I have to prove **T(n+1) = 4<sup>n+1</sup> - (-1)<sup>n+1</sup>**

Base Case: **T(0) = 4<sup>0</sup> - (-1)<sup>0</sup> = 1 - 1 = 0**

Induction Step: Assume T(n), prove T(n+1). I want to prove that **3T(n-1) + 4T(n-2) + (n+1) = 4<sup>n+1</sup> - (-1)<sup>n+1</sup>**

**1. 3T(n-1) + 4T(n-2) + (n+1)

2. 3[4<sup>n-1</sup> - (-1)<sup>n-1</sup>] + 4[4<sup>n-2</sup> - (-1)<sup>n-2</sup>] + (n+1)

3. 3[4<sup>n-1</sup> - (-1)<sup>n-1</sup>] + 4<sup>n-1</sup> - 4(-1)<sup>n-2</sup> + (n+1)

4. 3*4<sup>n-1</sup> - 3*(-1)<sup>n-1</sup> + 4<sup>n-1</sup> - 4(-1)<sup>n-2</sup> + (n+1)

5. 4*4<sup>n-1</sup> - 3*(-1)<sup>n-1</sup>  - 4(-1)<sup>n-2</sup> + (n+1)

6. 4<sup>n</sup> - 3*(-1)<sup>n-1</sup>  - 4(-1)<sup>n-2</sup> + (n+1)

7. 4<sup>n</sup> - [-1<sup>n-2</sup>(3(-1)-4)] + (n+1)

8. 4<sup>n</sup> - [-1<sup>n-2</sup>(-3-4)] + (n+1)

9. 4<sup>n</sup> - [-1<sup>n-2</sup>(-7)] + (n+1)

10. 4<sup>n</sup> - 1[-1<sup>n-2</sup>(-7)] + (n+1)

11. 4<sup>n</sup> -1<sup>n-1</sup>(-7) + (n+1)**

So that's as far as I've gone. I feel like I am almost there, but I am not sure what to do with the (-7) and the (n+1) at the end. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For the inductive step, you want to prove $T(n+1)=4^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}$. That is, you want to show that $3T(n)+4T(n-1)=4^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}$. Also, the recursion $3T(n)+4T(n-1)$ only holds for $n>1$ and so to apply induction you need to include $1$ in your base case.

Comment: oh my I think I am on the right track, but I forgot to change the induction step ! I will redo the proble with the correct inductive step and see what answer I receive. Hopefully it's the same as the solution given above since I havn't looked at it yet

Comment: oh yeah I solved it. Thanks for the hint !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoiler Alert
$$
\begin{align}
T(n+1) &= 3T(n)+4T(n-1)\\
&= 3(4^n-(-1)^n)+4(4^{n-1}-(-1)^{n-1})\\
&= (3+1)4^n-3(-1)^n-4(-1)^{n-1}\\
&= 4^{n+1}-(-1)^{n-1}(3(-1)^1+4)\\
&= 4^{n+1}-(-1)^{n-1}\\
&= 4^{n+1}-(-1)^{n+1}
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: He said not to solve it!

Comment: He does not have to read the hole thing.

Comment: i'll take a look at this after I try it a few more times :)  
Edit: got the solution !